# Expand a list from one dataframe to another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, expand

I was hoping to get help with the following:

I have a given df below of:

```
df
fruit   State  Count
apples     CA   45
apples     VT   54
apples     MI   18
pears      TX   20
pears      AZ   89
plums      NV   62
plums      ID   10
```

I took all the highest counts for each fruit per state, and was able to get something back like:

```
df2
fruit      State   Count
apples     VT      54
pears      AZ      89
plums      NV      62
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to get the 'State' values from df2 as a new column in df to look like something like this:

```
df
fruit   State  Count  Main
apples     CA   45    VT
apples     VT   54    VT
apples     MI   18    VT
pears      TX   20    AZ
pears      AZ   89    AZ
plums      NV   62    NV
plums      ID   10    NV
```

I can do something similar with the .transform() function, but i only know how to do that while calling the max function. Could i run transform on a df['list']? Or am i missing something else here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), but first need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for indices by column `State`:

```
df['new'] = df.set_index('State').groupby('fruit')['Count'].transform('idxmax').values
print (df)
    fruit State  Count new
0  apples    CA     45  VT
1  apples    VT     54  VT
2  apples    MI     18  VT
3   pears    TX     20  AZ
4   pears    AZ     89  AZ
5   plums    NV     62  NV
6   plums    ID     10  NV
```

Another solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by this `Series`:

```
s = (df.sort_values('Count', ascending= False)
       .drop_duplicates('fruit')
       .set_index('fruit')['State'])
print (s)
fruit
pears     AZ
plums     NV
apples    VT
Name: State, dtype: object

df['new'] = df['fruit'].map(s)
print (df)
    fruit State  Count new
0  apples    CA     45  VT
1  apples    VT     54  VT
2  apples    MI     18  VT
3   pears    TX     20  AZ
4   pears    AZ     89  AZ
5   plums    NV     62  NV
6   plums    ID     10  NV
```

Answer (score 2):

Two step :-) without `groupby`

```
df2=df.sort_values('Count').drop_duplicates('fruit',keep='last')
df['new']=df.fruit.map(df2.set_index('fruit').State)
df
Out[240]: 
    fruit State  Count new
0  apples    CA     45  VT
1  apples    VT     54  VT
2  apples    MI     18  VT
3   pears    TX     20  AZ
4   pears    AZ     89  AZ
5   plums    NV     62  NV
6   plums    ID     10  NV
```